# Does OCaml have syntax like Haskell's ++?

Tags: list, haskell, append, ocaml

I know OCaml has List.append, but does it have an operator like Haskell's `++`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For lists:

```
# (@);;
- : 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# [1;2;3] @ [4;5;6];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

For strings:

```
# (^);;
- : string -> string -> string = <fun>
# "abc" ^ "def";;
- : string = "abcdef"
```

Comment: There are many subtleties to such decisions. Haskell pays a penalty in performance. Lennart Augustsson just made the comment that this decision was a mistake in Haskell (at his CUFP 2011 talk).

Comment: If only Haskell used the name `++` instead of `mappend` for Monoids. Then it would work just as well on `Data.Text`, which is an instance of `Monoid`, and is much more efficient than char lists ;)

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could just say yourself

```
let (@) = List.append
```

or

```
let (++) = List.append
```

if noone had yet done it for you in the standard library.